# How to decompile python

Tags: decompilation, python

How can I decompile python 3.3 files ??

Can you please suggest me a tool for linux ubuntu 14.10 in specific

note easy decompiler didn't work for me :(

Comment: @perror I think this is not a duplicate bcoz i need specifically for python 3.3

Comment: @justsome et al:  I agree this is not a duplicate. The title probably should be adjusted to refer to version 3.3. I can speak from experience that decompiling Python 3.3 is very different from 2.7. Furthermore, the answers and accepted answer in the link won't work for 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is anything specific for Ubuntu, more than anything because the CPython byte-code is the same for all platforms, as far as I know.

Anyway, I think this is the tool you want: http://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/

Comment: the easy python decompiler didn't work for me :(

Comment: try this one, it works for all python versions: http://www.javadecompilers.com/pyc